# How to remove all elements in a list in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I have a birthbook as follows. How to write a function that empty the list.
birthBook::[(String,String,String)]
birthBook=[("dd","2","4")]

Comment: What is a birth book? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You can either (1) use the empty list where needed, or (2) if you really want a function, use something like: clearBirthBook = const []

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in Haskell. Haskell is a language where values are **immutable**. It means that once value are defined, they can't be changed. You are mistaking with imperative languages, where you could do

```
birthbook = [1,2,3]
birthbook = []
print birthbook // -> []
```

If you are confused, take a look at [the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_programming#Immutable_data).

> Purely functional programs typically operate on immutable data. Instead of altering existing values, altered copies are created and the original is preserved. Since the unchanged parts of the structure cannot be modified, they can often be shared between the old and new copies, which saves memory.

Answer (score 1):

if by *empty the list* you are talking about *something* like:

```
emptyBook :: [(String,String,String)] -> ()
```

that will turn

```
birthBook=[(...)]
```

with

```
emptyBook birthBook
```

into

```
birthBook=[]
```

then you *don't* - that's what it means to be immutable

---

what you do instead is pass your list/book around (maybe get fancy and put it into a state-monad) - than it's as simple as dropping the old value and just continue with `[]`

Or you move into `IO` and revert to imperative programming (using `IORef`s or something)